# monotouch asset library orientation

Tags: xamarin.ios, orientation, alassetslibrary

I have an app that allows users to select multiple images from the asset library.  The problem I'm having is that the orientation metadata is not stored when I "copy" the image from the asset library to a directory in my app's library.  The result is that images are sometimes upside down etc...

Below is the code from a unit test.  I have simplified and moved code onto separate lines for easy debugging.

This works, but does not copy the metadata:

```
private void getAssetFromURL(ALAsset asset) 
{
    NSError fileError;

    ALAssetRepresentation rep = asset.DefaultRepresentation;

    CGImage cgi = rep.GetImage();
    UIImage img = UIImage.FromImage(cgi);
    NSData jpegData = img.AsJPEG();
    jpegData.Save(pathToSave,true,out fileError);
}
```

If I change the code to include the orientation, I get an object reference error.  The jpegData is null and when I look at the CGImage data on the UIImage in debug I notice that it's null.  I do notice that the orientation does pass to the UIImage properly though.

```
private void getAssetFromURL(ALAsset asset) 
{
    NSError fileError;

    ALAssetRepresentation rep = asset.DefaultRepresentation;

    UIImageOrientation orientation = UIImageOrientation.Up;
    if (rep.Orientation != null && rep.Orientation != ALAssetOrientation.Up)
        orientation = (UIImageOrientation)rep.Orientation;

    CGImage cgi = rep.GetImage();
    UIImage img = UIImage.FromImage(cgi,rep.Scale,orientation);
    NSData jpegData = img.AsJPEG();  //data is null
    jpegData.Save(pathToSave,true,out fileError);  //throws object reference error
}
```

What am I doing wrong?  Is there an easy way without rotating the image to pass the orientation on to the JPEG?

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try doing the following, I never faced any orientation issue as such.

```
UIImageOrientation orientation = UIImageOrientation.Up;
ALAssetRepresentation assetRep = asset.DefaultRepresentation;
CGImage imgRef = assetRep.GetFullScreenImage ();
orientation = (UIImageOrientation)assetRep.Orientation;
UIImage Image = new UIImage(imgRef,1.0f,orientation);

using (NSData imageData = img.AsJPEG()) 
{
     Byte[] myByteArray = new Byte[imageData.Length];
     System.Runtime.InteropServices.Marshal.Copy(imageData.Bytes, myByteArray, 0, Convert.ToInt32(imageData.Length));
     string pathToSave = ""; //Assign your path
     if(!File.Exists(pathToSave))
     {
     File.WriteAllBytes (pathToSave, myByteArray);
     }
}
```

One more thing, I think if you use assetRep.GetFullScreenImage () instead of assetRep.GetImage () will solve your problem.

Hope it helps.